# Frequent Disconnects ubuntu desktop 12.10 x64 intel 82579V e1000e

Tags: networking, 12.10, intel

I'm having frequent disconnects with my new install of Ubuntu 12.10.  I tried updating the kernel driver to the latest intel release to no avail.  My expertise is spent.  It happens anywhere between 1 min and 10 min.  Any ideas?

syslog:

```
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188809] audit_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188813] type=1701 audit(1354398699.418:199): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d9205 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188817] type=1701 audit(1354398699.418:200): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d9205 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188820] type=1701 audit(1354398699.418:201): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d9205 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188823] type=1701 audit(1354398699.418:202): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d9205 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.188825] type=1701 audit(1354398699.418:203): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d9205 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:51:39 andromeda kernel: [  972.331419] type=1701 audit(1354398699.558:204): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=6039 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f26777d96b0 code=0x50000
Dec  1 13:53:12 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Dec  1 13:53:12 andromeda kernel: [ 1064.894387] e1000e: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5946
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86 on eth0.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda kernel: [ 1069.025288] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.11.17 on eth0.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.17.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> ((null)): removing resolv.conf from /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec  1 13:53:16 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Auto-activating connection '82579V'.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection '82579V'
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda kernel: [ 1084.938042] e1000e: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda kernel: [ 1084.938049] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda kernel: [ 1084.938815] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> dhclient started with pid 6080
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: 
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/e8:40:f2:e2:4d:86
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/e8:40:f2:e2:4d:86
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.17 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.11.17 from 192.168.11.1
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda dhclient: bound to 192.168.11.17 -- renewal in 33576 seconds.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   address 192.168.11.17
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   gateway 192.168.11.1
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   hostname 'andromeda'
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.11.1'
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   domain name 'hsd1.ca.comcast.net'
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.17.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:32 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Registering new address record for 192.168.11.17 on eth0.IPv4.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> ((null)): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: using nameserver 192.168.11.1#53
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Policy set '82579V' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:33 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Registering new address record for fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86 on eth0.*.
Dec  1 13:53:41 andromeda ntpdate[6154]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.000928 sec
Dec  1 13:53:50 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Dec  1 13:53:50 andromeda kernel: [ 1102.980003] e1000e: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 6080
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86 on eth0.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.11.17 on eth0.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.17.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda kernel: [ 1107.025959] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> ((null)): removing resolv.conf from /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec  1 13:53:54 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Auto-activating connection '82579V'.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection '82579V'
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda kernel: [ 1123.167668] e1000e: e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda kernel: [ 1123.167675] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda kernel: [ 1123.168430] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> dhclient started with pid 6212
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: 
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/e8:40:f2:e2:4d:86
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/e8:40:f2:e2:4d:86
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.17 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.11.17 from 192.168.11.1
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   address 192.168.11.17
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   gateway 192.168.11.1
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   hostname 'andromeda'
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.11.1'
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info>   domain name 'hsd1.ca.comcast.net'
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.17.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda dhclient: bound to 192.168.11.17 -- renewal in 35416 seconds.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:54:10 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Registering new address record for 192.168.11.17 on eth0.IPv4.
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> ((null)): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda dnsmasq[1907]: using nameserver 192.168.11.1#53
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Policy set '82579V' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda NetworkManager[1115]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec  1 13:54:11 andromeda dbus[800]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 13:54:12 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86.
Dec  1 13:54:12 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec  1 13:54:12 andromeda avahi-daemon[890]: Registering new address record for fe80::ea40:f2ff:fee2:4d86 on eth0.*.
Dec  1 13:54:19 andromeda ntpdate[6286]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.001142 sec
```

$ lspci -v

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2031
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f7f39000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

$ modinfo e1000e

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/net/e1000e/e1000e.ko
version:        2.1.4-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     0809529BE0BBC44883956AF
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000153Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000153Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001503sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001502sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001525sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000294Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001501sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001049sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001098sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000109Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001060sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       3.5.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:           CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
parm:           EEE:Enable/disable on parts that support the feature (array of int)
parm:           Node:[ROUTING] Node to allocate memory on, default -1 (array of int)
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of things I did appear to have solved the issue.

I installed the latest drivers from source. Found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/):.

I bought a CAT6 cable since I was using a cheap CAT5 cable (and it is a gigabit card) because it was suggested [here](http://communities.intel.com/message/161108#161108).

And finally I enabled some kernel boot parameters as follows in /etc/default/grub:

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash e1000e.IntMode=1,1 e1000e.InterruptThrottleRate=10000,10000"
```

Comment: That's an awful mix of things... (`pcie_aspm=off`, `acpi=off`, "from source"). These ACPI and PCIe ASPM adjustments should not be made on mobile PCs. You really want ACPI to function properly. Also on desktop PCs this is needed to be able to have your PC turned off by the OS and to do hot plugging of certain devices. And the `nomodeset` is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: Yeah I understood that ACPI is needed for laptops, but I had no idea it prevented me from shutting off the computer.  My computer is a desktop so I don't shut it off often but I did notice that I had to press the power button after I did a halt.  There are some parameters that I set on there for other devices as well.  I'll edit my answer for the relevant arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an answer but I have noticed this seems to be a common driver problem related to 'e1000e' because I also have the same problem.

I am in the middle of finding the solution now, but I have not found it yet. When I do I will post it here but if anybody finds solution in the meantime please post it.

Reference)
http://www.doxer.org/learn-linux/resolved-intel-e1000e-driver-bug-on-82574l-ethernet-controller-causing-network-blipping/